# Neo4j allShortestPaths Join

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have types: Site and Person. They have few relationship: SiteToPersonTypeA, SiteToPersonTypeB, SiteToSite

using query allShortestPaths:

```
MATCH (s:Site { Id: 1}),(p:Person { Id:4 }), sp = allShortestPaths((s)-[*]-(p))
where  ALL (n IN nodes(sp) WHERE n.Type = 'Some type')
RETURN sp
```

Next, create a new type:

```
CREATE (р:History { unixTimeFrom : 1461597080, unixTimeTo : 1461598080, Value:'someValue' })
```

Need JOIN Site with History and use filter by History fields

I don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

As a simple example, to "join" the Site with `Id` 1 to the History with the `Value` of "someValue", you can create a `HAS_HISTORY` relationship to connect the two, like so:

```
MATCH (s:Site { Id: 1}), (р:History {Value:'someValue' })
MERGE (s)-[:HAS_HISTORY]->(h);
```

This query uses `MERGE` (instead of `CREATE`) to avoid creating duplicate relationships.